# Strip HTML tags before indexing into elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working to index HTML files into elastic using Nodejs. However even before using the Nodejs, I tried to run following manual indexing which doesn't seems working. What I am missing?

Index sample HTML tag using html_strip filter:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/bhs/articles/_analyzer?tokenizer=standard&char_filters=html_strip' -d '
{
    "content" : "<title>Dilip Kumar</title>"
}'
```

Search to get all documents:

```
http://localhost:9200/bhs/articles/_search
```

It gives following as result:

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "bhs",
        "_type": "articles",
        "_id": "AUt2TGl9aadd5iLJ3mue",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "content": "<title>Dilip Kumar</title>"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Ideally it should not index  tag as I have used html_filter to strip tags.

Comment: I am looking in context for elasticsearch. Not javascript.

Comment: I see <title> tag is also indexed, therefore when i search for "title" then it comes as result. Seems like I am missing basics.

Comment: What is your mapping for the articles type - have you told it to use a custom analyzer?

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing in the returned search result is the stored content, i.e. this is not the individual terms that have been indexed.

```
"content": "<title>Dilip Kumar</title>"
```

To see what has been indexed is a little more challenging - the indexed terms are not designed to be returned to a user and instead only used when search.

However you can access and view them by using a script:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/bhs/articles/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
  "query" : {
    "match_all" : { }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "terms" : {
        "script": "doc[field].values",
        "params": {
            "field": "content"
        }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining _source. I don't want to index tags i.e. <title>. Currently I am able to search using "title" word as well which I don't want as "title" is part of <title>. What should i do to index content without HTML tags?

Comment: What is your mapping for the articles type - have you told it to use a custom analyzer?

Comment: By mistake I created two post as I was not aware that both are related to same problem....can you please check following post for mapping used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445684/why-html-tag-is-searchable-even-if-it-was-filtered-in-elastic-search/28446814?noredirect=1#comment45231786_28446814