# Why HTML tag is searchable even if it was filtered in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch and was testing html_strip filter. Ideally I should not be able to search on HTML tags. Following is steps.

Index:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/foo/test/_analyzer?tokenizer=standard&char_filters=html_strip' -d '
{
    "content" : "<title>Dilip Kumar</title>"
}'
```

Search:

```
http://localhost:9200/foo/test/_search?tokenizer=standard&char_filters=html_strip&q=title
```

Result:

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.2169777,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "foo",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "_analyzer",
        "_score": 0.2169777,
        "_source": {
          "content": "<title>Dilip Kumar</title>"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
As suggested; I used following mapping and repeated above steps after deleting the existing index however still I am able to search markup.

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/foo " -d'
{
  "foo": {
    "settings": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "html_analyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "standard",
              "lowercase",
              "stop",
              "asciifolding"
            ],
            "char_filter": [
              "html_strip"
            ]
          },
          "whitespace_analyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [
              "standard",
              "lowercase",
              "stop",
              "asciifolding"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "test": {
        "properties": {
          "content": {
            "type": "string",
            "index_analyzer": "html_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply analyzer before indexing on the mapping. 
This will make sure all documents that are indexed passes through this mapping and all the tags are stripped out before indexing.
In your case , you applied the analyzer while querying and this will only affect your search phrase and not the data you search.

You can read more on creating mapping [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html)

I dont believe there is format like this -

```
http://localhost:9200/foo/test/_search?tokenizer=standard&char_filters=html_strip&q=title
```

Rather if you can set the analyzer as follows , it should work fine -

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/foo " -d'
{
  "foo": {
    "settings": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "html_analyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "standard",
              "lowercase",
              "stop",
              "asciifolding"
            ],
            "char_filter": [
              "html_strip"
            ]
          },
          "whitespace_analyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [
              "standard",
              "lowercase",
              "stop",
              "asciifolding"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "test": {
        "properties": {
          "content": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "html_analyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Here i made the analyzer common for indexing and searching

Comment: I didn't get you. I have applied char_filters=html_strip on indexing as well. I am new to elasticsearch....not able to figure out your observation. In the mean time I am reading how to create mapping as per documentation you shared.

Comment: I used mapping but still same issue. Updated post to add the mapping details. Please look.

Comment: I tried new mapping...but still I am able to search title which should not be. Can you please share three steps 1. Add mapping 2. Index HTML markup 3. Search query