# Elasticsearch : Strip HTML tags before indexing docs with html_strip filter not working

Tags: html, elasticsearch, filter, full-text-search, mapping

**Given** I have specified my html strip char filter in my custom analyser

**When** I index a document with html content

**Then** I expect the html to be strip out of the indexed content

**And** on retrieval the returned doc from the index shoult not contain hmtl

**ACTUAL**: 
The indexed doc contained html
The retrieved doc contained html

I have tried specifying the analyzer as index_analyzer as one would expect and a few others out of desperation search_analyzer and analyzer. Non seem to have any effect on the doc being indexed or retrieve.

## Test Doc Indexing against HTML_Strip Analysed field :

**REQUEST : Example POST document with html content**

```
POST /html_poc_v2/html_poc_type/02
{
  "description": "Description <p>Some d&eacute;j&agrave; vu <a href=\"http://somedomain.com>\">website</a>",
  "title": "Title <p>Some d&eacute;j&agrave; vu <a href=\"http://somedomain.com>\">website</a>",
  "body": "Body <p>Some d&eacute;j&agrave; vu <a href=\"http://somedomain.com>\">website</a>"
}
```

*Expected* : indexed data to have being parsed through the html analyser.
*Actual* : data is indexed with html

**RESPONSE**

```
{
   "_index": "html_poc_v2",   "_type": "html_poc_type",   "_id": "02", ...
   "_source": {
      "description": "Description <p>Some d&eacute;j&agrave; vu <a href=\"http://somedomain.com>\">website</a>",
      "title": "Title <p>Some d&eacute;j&agrave; vu <a href=\"http://somedomain.com>\">website</a>",
      "body": "Body <p>Some d&eacute;j&agrave; vu <a href=\"http://somedomain.com>\">website</a>"
   }
}
```

## Settings and Doc Mapping

```
PUT /html_poc_v2
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_html_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "html_poc_type": {
        "properties": {
          "body": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "my_html_analyzer"
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "my_html_analyzer"
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "string",
            "search_analyser": "my_html_analyzer"
          },
          "urlTitle": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## Test to proof Custom Analyser works perfectly:

**REQUEST**

```
GET /html_poc_v2/_analyze?analyzer=my_html_analyzer
{<p>Some d&eacute;j&agrave; vu <a href="http://somedomain.com>">website</a>}
```

**Response**

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "Some",… "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "déjà",… "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "vu",…  "position": 3
      },
      {
         "token": "website",… "position": 4
      }
   ]
}
```

## Under the hood

going under the hood with an in-line script proofs further that my html analyser must have been skipped

**REQUEST**

```
GET /html_poc_v2/html_poc_type/_search?pretty=true
{
  "query" : {
    "match_all" : { }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "terms" : {
        "script": "doc[field].values",
        "params": {
            "field": "title"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**RESPONSE**

```
{ …
   "hits": { ..
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "html_poc_v2",
            "_type": "html_poc_type",
            …
            "fields": {
               "terms": [
                  [
                     "a",
                     "agrave",
                     "d",
                     "eacute",
                     "href",
                     "http",
                     "j",
                     "p",
                     "some",
                     "somedomain.com",
                     "title",
                     "vu",
                     "website"
                  ]
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Similar to this question here : [Why HTML tag is searchable even if it was filtered in elastic search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445684/why-html-tag-is-searchable-even-if-it-was-filtered-in-elastic-search)

I have also read this amazing doc : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-htmlstrip-charfilter.html

ES version : 1.7.2

Please Help.

Answer (score 9):

You are confusing the "***_source***" field in the response to return what is being analyzed and indexed.
It looks like your expectation is that the `_source` field in response returns  the analyzed document. This is incorrect.

From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html) ;

> The _source field contains the original JSON document body that was
>   passed at index time. The _source field itself is not indexed (and
>   thus is not searchable), but it is stored so that it can be returned
>   when executing fetch requests, like get or search.

Ideally in the above case wherein you want to format the source data for presentation purposes it should be done at the  client end.

However that being said one way to achieve it for the above use case is using [script fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-script-fields.html) and [keyword-tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html) as follows  :

```
PUT test
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "my_html_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "char_filter": [
                  "html_strip"
               ]
            },
            "parsed_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "keyword",
               "char_filter": [
                  "html_strip"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "test": {
         "properties": {
            "body": {
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "my_html_analyzer",
               "fields": {
                  "parsed": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "analyzer": "parsed_analyzer"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}


PUT test/test/1 
{
    "body" : "Title <p> Some d&eacute;j&agrave; vu <a href='http://somedomain.com'> website </a> <span> this is inline </span></p> "
}

GET test/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "match_all" : { }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "terms" : {
        "script": "doc[field].values",
        "params": {
            "field": "body.parsed"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
   "_index": "test",
   "_type": "test",
   "_id": "1",
   "_score": 1,
   "fields": {
        "terms": [
            "Title \n Some déjà vu  website   this is inline \n "
           ]
        }
   }
```

note I believe the above is a bad idea since stripping the html tags could be easily  achived on the client end and you would have much more control with regard to formatting than depending on a work around such as this. More importantly it maybe  performant doing it on the client side.

Comment: It is the *_source* field too that I would like to prevent from having the html tags. In other words alongside not indexing html tags, I will like not to return html on GET/Search neither. Any Idea/Suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Thanks a bunch keety. Great suggest, though a work around, you are right, not a good idea. It would also require enabling scripting on my Live cluster.  Also would not be compatible with custom elasticsearch endpoint _plugins that we have that are tied to pull fields from the _source of my said documents such as title, body and description.

Comment: So that means the goal you want is not achievable without compromising security?

Comment: I actually found a solution to this - I'll be posting my answer below! :)

Comment: @susieloo_ you didn't post it

Comment: @mel They deleted my post because it was a duplicate. Check out my answer on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386354/how-to-modify-source-field-of-an-elasticsearch-document/40667511#40667511