# How to modify _source field of an Elasticsearch document

Tags: javascript, html, elasticsearch

Question: **Is there any way to clean the html from the _source of the doc?**
The stripping of the html can be periodic, triggered or ideally on the fly as its being indexed.

I have in coming data into elasticsearch being indexed against an Analyser that is stripping unwanted htmls tags before its being index.

On Queries/Gets its the _source field with the original content that has the htmls that is returned to clients.

Note:

- I can't clean up the data before being passed to elasticsearch, I don't have control over this.
- My clients retrieving the data from elasticsearch could do the stripping with javascript before presenting the data, but not an option neither.

Comment: Using `transform` you can edit/change the `_source`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/mapping-transform.html. But note that it is deprecated starting with 2.0.0 with no replacement.

Comment: Thanks @andrei-stefan, Ideally not via a deprecated means. Also note as per the `transform` documentation "the result isn’t stored in the source".

Comment: You are not able to change _source. The _source contains your data which you put into the elasticsearch. All mappings you defined are set on your input json object but they don't modify _source.

Answer (score 2):

_source simply stores the JSON that has been indexed. You cannot change it.

Now if you want to completely strip out the html prior to indexing and storing the content as is, you can use the mapper attachment plugin - in which when you define the mapping, you can categorize the content_type to be "html."

The mapper attachment is useful for many things especially if you are handling multiple document types, but most notably - I believe just using this for the purpose of stripping out the html tags is sufficient enough (which you cannot do with the html_strip char filter).

Just a forewarning though - NONE of the html tags will be stored. So if you do need those tags somehow, I would suggest defining another field to store the original content. Another note: You cannot specify multifields for mapper attachment documents, so you would need to store that outside of the mapper attachment document. See my working example below.

You'll need to result in this mapping:

```
{
  "html5-es" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "document" : {
        "properties" : {
          "delete" : {
            "type" : "boolean"
          },
          "file" : {
            "type" : "attachment",
            "fields" : {
              "content" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "store" : true,
                "term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets",
                "analyzer" : "autocomplete"
              },
              "author" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "store" : true,
                "term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets"
              },
              "title" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "store" : true,
                "term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets",
                "analyzer" : "autocomplete"
              },
              "name" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "date" : {
                "type" : "date",
               "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
              },
              "keywords" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "content_type" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
          "content_length" : {
                "type" : "integer"
              },
              "language" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "hash_id" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "path" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "raw_content" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "store" : true,
            "term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets",
            "analyzer" : "raw"
          },
          "title" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : { //insert your own settings here },
    "warmers" : { }
  }
}
```

Such that in NEST, I will assemble the content as such:

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
attachment.Content =   Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes("path/to/document"));
attachment.ContentType = "html";

Document document = new Document();
document.File = attachment;
document.RawContent = InsertRawContentFromString(originalText);
```

I have tested this in Sense - results are as follows:

```
"file": {
    "_content": "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",
    "_content_length": 0,
    "_content_type": "html",
    "_date": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "_title": "Topic10"
},
"delete": false,
"raw_content": "<h1>Topic10</h1><p>Delete this text and replace it with your own content. Check your mailbox.</p><p> </p><p>asdf</p><p> </p><p>10</p><p> </p><p>Lavender.</p><p> </p><p>10/6 12:03</p><p> </p><p>5 09</p><p> </p><p>11 47</p><p> </p><p>Halloween is in October.</p><p> </p><p>jog</p>"
},
"highlight": {
"file.content": [
    "\n    <em>Topic10</em>\n\n    Delete this text and replace it with your own content. Check your mailbox.\n\n     \n\n    asdf\n\n     \n\n    10\n\n     \n\n    Lavender.\n\n     \n\n    10/6 12:03\n\n     \n\n    5 09\n\n     \n\n    11 47\n\n     \n\n    Halloween is in October.\n\n     \n\n    jog\n\n  "
    ]
}
```