# Elasticsearch: match a pattern using regexp with a specific order

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I would like to know if it is possible to use regexp in Elasticsearch to match a pattern with different strings in a specific order.

For example for the string: `still_adv be_aux pick_verb up_adp the_det bus_noun` I want to match the combination of words with the tag ADV+AUX+VERB so here it will be `still_adv be_aux pick_verb`.

I will use this regexp:

```
{
   "query_string": 
    {
     "fields": ["sentences_features.tagger.annotation],
     "query": "*(.*_adv) (be_aux) (.*_verb)*"
    }
}
```

However, this regexp is not working and matches each word separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the whole group in parentheses:

```
*((.*_adv) (be_aux) (.*_verb))*
```

But for future reference, it'd be better to split these annotation tags into more easily searchable key-value pairs like:

```
[ {word_type: 'adv', text: 'still', position: 0 }, {...}, ... ]
```

It's more work at the beginning but will come in handy later.

---

EDIT

After setting up an index with a `keyword` field mapping

```
PUT myind
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "annot": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and syncing a few docs

```
// valid
POST myind/_doc
{
  "annot": "and_CCONJ other_ADJ driver_NOUN_b1 professional_ADJ"
}

// valid
POST myind/_doc
{
  "annot": "xyz other_ADJ driver_NOUN_b1 xyz"
}

// invalid
POST myind/_doc
{
  "annot": "and_CCONJ other_ADJ professional_ADJ driver_NOUN_b1"
}
```

we can use the a `regexp` query on the `.keyword` like so:

```
GET myind/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "annot.keyword": "(.* )?other_ADJ [a-zA-Z*]*_NOUN_b1( .*)?"
    }
  }
}
```

and if you don't care what's in between of the two tokens you can use

```
(.* )?other_ADJ( .*)?[a-zA-Z*]*_NOUN_b1( .*)?
```

For HTML tag stripping check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37351900/8160318).

Comment: It is not working with the group parentheses.the regexp still matches each word separately.

Comment: How does the key-value search work? Not sure to understand as I don't know the position of each word before search?

Comment: Can you share some more sample docs which are matching and shouldn't be?

Comment: for example this regexp `*((other_adj) (.*_noun_b1))*` returns this  `and_CCONJ <em>other_ADJ</em> professional_ADJ driver_NOUN_a2` and it should not be returned as I just want `other_adj` followed by `.*_noun_b1`

Comment: It works better thanks. Is it possible to highlight the group and not all the string?