# Customize Elasticsearch search results to don't show the HTML tags

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to make a search API for my blog, I was storing all the data inside an elasticsearch in HTML format to use it in full text search as fast as I can, but HTML tags bother me to search inside my contents. with many searches I was found an answer about how I could ignore them in search but I can't filtering them out to don't show in results is there any way to do this?

Now I search and get the results with the following:

```
POST /test/_search HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 68

{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "html": "more"
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```json
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 0.2876821,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.2876821,
                "_source": {
                    "html": "<html><body><h1 style=\"font-family: Arial\">Test</h1> <span>More test</span></body></html>"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But I want to get something like this:

```json
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 0.2876821,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.2876821,
                "_source": {
                    "html": "Test More test"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **[HTML strip character filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-htmlstrip-charfilter.html#analysis-htmlstrip-charfilter-analyze-ex)** in your mapping. Through it you will remove HTML elements from your document.
I used this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37351900/elasticsearch-strip-html-tags-before-indexing-docs-with-html-strip-filter-not) to try to get close to your result.

```
PUT idx_test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_pattern_replace_filter": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "\n",
          "replacement": ""
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ]
        },
        "parsed_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ],
          "filter": [
            "my_pattern_replace_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "html": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "text",
            "fielddata": true,
            "analyzer": "parsed_analyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST idx_test/_doc
{
  "html": """<html><body><h1 style="font-family: Arial">Test</h1> <span>More test</span></body></html>"""
}

GET idx_test/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "html_raw": {
      "script": "doc['html.raw']"
    }
  }, 
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "html": "more"
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "idx_test",
    "_id": "0b-UqoMBCzQxtx05B-WH",
    "_score": 0.2876821,
    "fields": {
      "html_raw": [
        "Test More test"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```