# Elasticsearch Highlight the result of script fields

Tags: elasticsearch

In the [last question that I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73967099/customize-elasticsearch-search-results-to-dont-show-the-html-tags) I want to remove the HTML tags in my search results, After that I thought I could highlite the results with a common query, But in the highlighting field I got other html contents that you removed with script. Would you please help me to highlight the results without html tags that I saved in my db?

My mapping and settings:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_pattern_replace_filter": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "\n",
          "replacement": ""
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ]
        },
        "parsed_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ],
          "filter": [
            "my_pattern_replace_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "html": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "text",
            "fielddata": true,
            "analyzer": "parsed_analyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search Query:

```
POST idx_test/_search

{
  "script_fields": {
    "raw": {
      "script": "doc['html.raw']"
    }
  }, 
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "html": "more"
    }
  },"highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "*":{ "pre_tags" : ["<strong>"], "post_tags" : ["</strong>"] }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
"hits": [
    {
        "_index": "idx_test2",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "GijDsYMBjgX3UBaguGxc",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "fields": {
            "raw": [
                "Test More test"
            ]
        },
        "highlight": {
            "html": [
                "<html><body><h1 style=\"font-family: Arial\">Test</h1> <span><strong>More</strong> test</span></body></html>"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Result that I want to get:

```
"hits": [
    {
        "_index": "idx_test2",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "GijDsYMBjgX3UBaguGxc",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "fields": {
            "raw": [
                "Test <strong>More</strong> test"
            ]
        }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought of another solution. You could index two fields, the original html and the html_extract which has only the text.
You would have to use a processor to just index the text coming from the message and highligths would work.

**Mapping**

```
PUT idx_html_strip
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "html": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "html_extract": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Processor Pipeline**

```
PUT /_ingest/pipeline/pipe_html_strip
{
  "description": "_description",
  "processors": [
    {
      "html_strip": {
        "field": "html",
        "target_field": "html_extract"
      }
    },
    {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "ctx['html_raw'] = ctx['html_raw'].replace('\n',' ').trim()"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Index Data**

Note the use ?pipeline=pipe_html_strip

```
POST idx_html_strip/_doc?pipeline=pipe_html_strip
{
  "html": """<html><body><h1 style=\"font-family: Arial\">Test</h1> <span><strong>More</strong> test</span></body></html>"""
}
```

**Query**

```
GET idx_html_strip/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source,hits.hits.highlight
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "More",
      "fields": ["html", "html_extract"]
    }
  },"highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "*":{ "pre_tags" : ["<strong>"], "post_tags" : ["</strong>"] }
    }
  }
}
```

**Results**

```
{
  "hits": {
    "hits": [
      {
        "_source": {
          "html": """<html><body><h1 style=\"font-family: Arial\">Test</h1> <span><strong>More</strong> test</span></body></html>""",
          "html_extract": "Test More test"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "html": [
            """<html><body><h1 style=\"font-family: Arial\">Test</h1> <span><strong><strong>More</strong></strong> test</span></body>"""
          ],
          "html_extract": [
            "Test <strong>More</strong> test"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```